# I am trying to style my map to make it darker but its not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, dictionary, frontend

I have tried styling my map by implementing google maps wizards customization JSON, but it is not working I tried different ways to structure the code with no result just the map. Due to the lenght of the code I replaced the JSON code with JSON.

I tried different structures and researching solutions. Thanks for helping

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import DrawerNavigator from './Menu/DrawerNavigator'
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

 var region = {
    latitude: 37.78825,
    longitude: -122.4324,
    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
  };
  var mapStyle = JSON




export default class SettingScreen extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View style = {styles.container}> 
< MapView style = {styles.container}
    initialRegion={region}
      customMapStyle={mapStyle}/>

         </View>

        )
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#0000',
        justifyContent: 'center',

    }
});
```

Comment: can you share your JSON styling object? i believe the issue is due to JSON not being readable.

Comment: @kenmistry sure: but it's too long so here is the link https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/      all you have to do is click on create style, select Aubergine from the available themes and click finish, the JSON will appear

Answer (score 0):

alright, i have created a styling JSON object as per your instructions and set up an example [here](https://snack.expo.io/@kenmistry/simple-map-styling-test). i didnt face an issue with your code, except for a missing semi-colon from the `mapStyle` variable. perhaps, it is the reason why the styling is not loading properly.

Answer (score 0):

@kenmistry you are actually having the same result I have, usually, it should show a map with a dark blueish background what I got from your code same as mine is a standard map. er is the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: i wasnt aware that you were referring to the Apple Maps on ios. so your implementation of the theme from google map styling wizard isnt going to work here. you will need a styling tool for Apple Maps instead.